# Modify a background with CSS /

Tags: css, wordpress, background

I am using Wordpress and i try to change the background of this website: http://evolum.org (the grey) and i want to put this one: https://greatives.eu/themes/movedo/ (behind the movedo word)

I am trying to put this on the Wordpress additional CSS editor:

```
element.style {
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(132, 84, 226) 0%, rgb(6, 82, 253) 100%); }
```

instead of:

```
element.style {
    background-image: url(http://evolum.org/wp-content/uploads/2000/01/grve-dummy-sample-image-large.png);
```

when I inspect the item and change it manually it works, but when i modify it on the wordpress editor it doesnt work!

i think it's maybe because it have multiple 'element.style', how to designate the right item to the wordpress editor?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a Child theme to your WordPress Installation. The child theme’s style.css should overwrite all other styles of main theme if you use same ids/classes as they which are used when you inspect the items.

For childtheme creation : 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: i try to install the child theme but its the same thing; I need to explain to the editor what 'element.style' i want to modify but i dont know how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like, that the background image for that element has not been implemented in the templates stylesheet, but with a visual composer. 
In your code  there is the following line http://evolum.org/:52:

```
.vc_custom_1474289280143{background-image: url(http://evolum.org/wp-content/uploads/2000/01/grve-dummy-sample-image-large.png?id=13180) !important;background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;}.vc_custom_1474289319001{padding-right: 31% !important;padding-left: 31% !important;}
```

The styles are directly being applied. You would want to open the visual composer and just change the settings for the background. If that does not let you enter css, you can always go back to the Wordpress editor and go to the code-view.
There you can search for the "vc_custom_1474289319001" and change the settings manually.

Edit: I have just inspected the element again and the correct selector for the background-element is:

```
div.grve-bg-image.grve-bg-image-id-15279.show
```

Please be aware, that neither the inline styles nor the css overwrites are considered good practice. Visual composers usually produce messy code and overwrites will make it harder to maintain code. Yet it can be a practical solution, if you cannot or don't want to invest a lot of time.
The best practice would be to write a new class (or id) for those styles and apply it to the element.

By the way: The template authors on themeforest usually provide great support, in most cases you'll just need to authenticate with your purchase code.

Comment: hey :) thanks you for ur message. I managed to change the background by directly modifying the php code. however now when I open the visual editor the loading is infinite and I can not modify anything. there is no change oprion of the background in the visual editor ...

thanks anyway!

Comment: Changing the background screws up the visual editor? Are you sure, that your code is correct? There should be no need to touch any php, just the css. 
Anyway: There must be a reasonable way to change that background. Have you gone through all the options in the visual editor? 
If that does not work out, try using the selector that I posted within additional css.
You could still ask the theme authors, which will save you some time.

Comment: Have a look here: https://visualcomposer.io/docs/design-options/element-background/

Comment: hey lennart! thanks u, u put me on the right way. I managed to change the color of the background via the CSS editor of the visual editor (it did not work in that of wordpress). however the option you sent me to change the background is not present in my visual editor. now it only remains to add the effect "wave" via the CSS editor via the visual editor. how to add the effect that is not present base in the template without touching the php? thank you in advance :) (fuck google translate :p)

Comment: What visual composer are you using? Is a different version of the same one I sent you?
Could you elaborate on where the problem remains? I did not get that.